# Is there a way to use the dateadd() in the where clause in a between statement?

Tags: sql, where-clause, dateadd

Here's my problem.

In my `where` clause I am trying to use the `between` clause with dates. In the second date I add, I need it to return the day after the date that is being input.

For example: `where DATE between '2015-05-01' and '2015-05-31'` is what I would like the user to input, but I would like the database to read it as `where DATE between '2015-05-01' and '2015-06-01'`

I have tried:
`where DATE between '2015-05-01' and dateadd('d', 1, '2015-05-31')`

which obviously gives my a syntax error. I have also tried to use a sub query, which also did not work.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions that would help? Or is this not possible in SQL? Any advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: what data type is your  `Where DATE` ? date or string ? btw, dont call your date field `DATE` reserved word, called `start_date` or `myDate`

Comment: You are talking about dateadd (which is a T-SQL function), but tagged it mysql. Which one is it?

Comment: Don't put quotes around the `d` (first argument).

Comment: DATE is actually not my field name, I was using it as an example

Comment: the MySQL tag was in error, im and running it on PCC

Comment: Even without the quotes around the D it still gives a syntax error

Comment: What is PCC ? Is sql server?

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms186819(v=sql.120).aspx

d without quotes

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/814a7/7)**

```
select *
from Table1
where mydate between '2015-10-02' and dateadd(d, 2, '2015-10-02')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the apostrophe around the d:  `dateadd('d', 1, '2015-05-31')`.

You can write the statement as `where DATE between '2015-05-01' and dateadd(d, 1, '2015-05-31')`.